# UITableView and thumbnails

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`UITableView` has `UIImageView`, all images has the same size. But when I starting scroll or selecting row, some images can change size. I cannot understand why. Or how to make an imageview of a fixed size in a table row?

[image]

Comment: Please show your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" code..

Comment: Can you please explore `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
` ?

Comment: - (WTANewsTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WTANewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WTANewsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

Comment: "configureCell" implementation: http://freetexthost.com/usccsswr1h

Answer (score 1):

Use UIGraphicsImageContext with the table view cell image view like :

```
UIImage *thumbNail = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
// Setting thumbnail image
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 40);// Sample image size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
[thumbNail drawInRect:imageRect];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.. Use custom cell and set imageView's frame there.